# Get selected value from SelectListItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I've got a problem with getting selected value from `SelectListItem`.

Here is my model:

```
public class GiveCourseNameModel
{
    public string SelectedCourse { get; set; }
    public float CourseValue { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> getAllCourseList()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> myList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var data = new[]{
             new SelectListItem{ Value="1",Text="AUD"},
             new SelectListItem{ Value="2",Text="CAD"},
             new SelectListItem{ Value="3",Text="CHF"},
             new SelectListItem{ Value="4",Text="CZK"},
             new SelectListItem{ Value="5",Text="DKK"},
             new SelectListItem{ Value="6",Text="EUR"},
             new SelectListItem{ Value="7",Text="GBP"},
             new SelectListItem{ Value="8",Text="HKD"},
             new SelectListItem{ Value="9",Text="JPY"},
             new SelectListItem{ Value="10",Text="LTL"},
             new SelectListItem{ Value="11",Text="LVL"},
             new SelectListItem{ Value="12",Text="NOK"},
             new SelectListItem{ Value="13",Text="PLN"},
             new SelectListItem{ Value="14",Text="RUB"},
             new SelectListItem{ Value="15",Text="SEK"},
             new SelectListItem{ Value="16",Text="UAH"},
             new SelectListItem{ Value="17",Text="USD"},
             new SelectListItem{ Value="18",Text="XDR"},
             new SelectListItem{ Value="19",Text="ZAR"},
         };
        myList = data.ToList();
        return myList;
    }

}
```

And Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index( GiveCourseNameModel model, string selectedCourse)
    {
        var nbpClient = new NBPSoapClient();            
        model.CourseValue = nbpClient.GiveCourse(); // here i want to insert SelectedCourse value like "EUR"             
        nbpClient.Close();
        return View(model);
    }
```

And HTML:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCourse,
new SelectList(Model.getAllCourseList(), "Value", "Text"), 
"-Select course-", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

My question is: how can I get the value of `SelectedCourse`, because I need to pass it as string to another method?

Comment: `model.CourseValue` should give you the value in your http post action method

Comment: Side note: usually you'd create custom class for items in `SelectedList`... `SelectedListItem` is designed to represent currently selected value and not used as item in the list...

Answer (score 0):

Your `model.SelectedCourse` should have the value for `SelectedCourse` in model binding.